# set date closed trac ticket

Tags: trac

I have a set of tickets that were managed via a primitive MS Excel sheet. 
The worksheet was as follows

Opened Date | Closed Date | Ticket Content

I want to put them on trac in order to have a complete overview of the tickets opened-closed and the performance of the dev team. However out of the box trac doesn't allow me to set an opened/closed date for a ticket in the past.

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had a similar demand. I resolved it by batch-import with the help of [TicketImportPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketImportPlugin).

I used a custom field due_date of type text. Calculating POSIX (micro)second time stamp needed some custom formula, but worked sufficiently well. These numbers where imported, and I changed field type to date afterwards. Note that I used a patched Trac code, that entered Trac upstream for version 1.1dev meant for 1.2 now. Another option would be to use the [DateFieldPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DateFieldPlugin), that deals with date strings internally. But why bother, of you know, that you could use could get [true custom time fields](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/Proposals/TracTicketsCustomTimeFields) supported by Trac core right-away?

I did alter creation date/time too. This has been done by importing another custom field, and copying values back to the time column of `ticket` db table. A bit of dirty hand-work on configuration and database, but once figured out it worked like a charm and I had 3000+ issues of many years imported with historically correct time stamps in a few minutes.